# Need help with creating image upload form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not really gr8 with ajax and javascript so I ask for help. Here is the deal, I have the image form upload working the old fashion way:

```
<form action="db/photo/do_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  <fieldset id="upload_form">
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

    </fieldset>
  <button type="button" class="ui-state-default">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

What I want is to make web page more attractive by making this with ajax, how can I do this :

**Once the Upload button is clicked**
- Start uploading the image
- Then while the image is uploading display some kind of ajax-loader
- When image is done uploading print out something like thank you

I have a php part already implemented-working I just need some help with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you can't directly do a file upload via XMLHTTPRequest (i.e., "ajax").  You have to post a form.

Now, what you could do is something like this:

- Direct the form "target" to an iframe hidden on the page (just declare an iframe, give it an "id" and a "name" because I'm never sure which one "target" refers to :-) and keep it "display: none")
- In the form "submit", update something on the page to start a throbber (just reveal a simple animated GIF, or something more fancy if you like)
- Have the server send back to a response (which, remember, will end up in our hidden iframe) that's a dummy page with a little javascript in it to tell the parent page that it's time to hide/stop the animation.

Not fancy, and you can't make the animation depend on the file size, but it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Javascript to catch the 'action' before you get sent to the next page, and thereafter, use JS to submit the form.

For example (using jQuery),

```
 $('button').click(
    function() {
        $('form').submit();
        $('div.result').html('<p>Thanks a bunch!</p>');
        return false;
    }
 );
```

Changing a 'loading picture' to "Thanks!" would require some kind of signal from the server. I just started using AJAX, so perhaps someone more familiar with such functions could add to this? Cheers. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using [redy to go and fancy](http://www.uploadify.com/) solution

+edit+

[Lightweight and not so fancy](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html)

Comment: This looks nice, but I'd preffer to write couple lines of code instead of using the whole plugin, it adds +kbs to my page which is already kidda heavy

Comment: Everything more complicated than Hello World is buggy... Anyway there are other, much smaller solutions for uploading files, like using iframe http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html Callbacks also supported so that should do it - on start hide the form, add gif image as 'ajax-loader' and on complete hide image and show 'Thank you'.

Comment: don't be offended by the down vote, its not just me its whole bunch of people, chk the twitter for uploadify you'll see people saying some shitty stuff, even the demo is not working properly, I personally prefer http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ it works great independently of any js framework and its even possible to use it with jquery UI, you should chk it out as well ..cheers